# Overriding __eq__ and __hash__ to compare a dict attribute of two instances

Tags: python, compare

I'm struggling to understand how to correctly compare objects based on an underlying dict attribute that each instance possesses.

Since I'm overriding `__eq__`, do I need to override `__hash__` as well?  I haven't a firm grasp on when/where to do so and could really use some help.

I created a simple example below to illustrate the maximum recursion exception that I've run into.  A `RegionalCustomerCollection` organizes account IDs by geographical region. `RegionalCustomerCollection` objects are said to be equal if the regions and their respective `accountid`s are.  Essentially, all `items()` should be equal in content.

```
from collections import defaultdict

class RegionalCustomerCollection(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.region_accountids = defaultdict(set) 

    def get_region_accountid(self, region_name=None):
        return self.region_accountids.get(region_name, None)

    def set_region_accountid(self, region_name, accountid):
        self.region_accountids[region_name].add(accountid)

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if (other == self):
            return True

        if isinstance(other, RegionalCustomerCollection):
            return self.region_accountids == other.region_accountids

        return False 

    def __repr__(self):
        return ', '.join(["{0}: {1}".format(region, acctids) 
                          for region, acctids 
                          in self.region_accountids.items()])
```

Let's create two object instances and populate them with some sample data:

```
>>> a = RegionalCustomerCollection()
>>> b = RegionalCustomerCollection()
>>> a.set_region_accountid('northeast',1)
>>> a.set_region_accountid('northeast',2)
>>> a.set_region_accountid('northeast',3)
>>> a.set_region_accountid('southwest',4)
>>> a.set_region_accountid('southwest',5)
>>> b.set_region_accountid('northeast',1)
>>> b.set_region_accountid('northeast',2)
>>> b.set_region_accountid('northeast',3)
>>> b.set_region_accountid('southwest',4)
>>> b.set_region_accountid('southwest',5)
```

Now let's try to compare the two instances and generate the recursion exception:

```
>>> a == b
... 
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

Comment: You need to implement `__eq__` and `__hash__` if you want to use an object as a dictionary key. You don't necessarily need `__hash__` just for the comparison (unless you want to do e.g. `hash(self) == hash(other)`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your object shouldn't return a hash because it's mutable.  If you put this object into a dictionary or set and then change it afterward, you may never be able to find it again.

In order to make an object unhashable, you need to do the following:

```
class MyClass(object):
    __hash__ = None
```

This will ensure that the object is unhashable.

```
 [in] >>> m = MyClass()
 [in] >>> hash(m)
[out] >>> TypeError: unhashable type 'MyClass'
```

Does this answer your question?  I'm suspecting not because you were explicitly looking for a **hash** function.

As far as the RuntimeError you're receiving, it's because of the following line:

```
    if self == other:
        return True
```

That gets you into an infinite recursion loop.  Try the following instead:

```
    if self is other:
        return True
```

Comment: Thank you, Steve.  Your explanation is clear and solution to eliminate the recursion works.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to override `__hash__` to compare two objects (you'll need to if you want custom hashing, i.e. to improve performance when inserting into sets or dictionaries).

Also, you have infinite recursion here:

```
    def __eq__(self, other):
        if (other == self):
            return True

        if isinstance(other, RegionalCustomerCollection):
            return self.region_accountids == other.region_accountids

        return False
```

If both objects are of type `RegionalCustomerCollection` then you'll have infinite recursion since `==` calls `__eq__`.

Comment: Thanks, Rodrigo, for clarifying the ____hash____ override use case (performance) .